# C# Pattern matching with an or condition

Tags: c#, pattern-matching

Is it possible to use an OR condition within a if statement when using pattern matching?

I have a pattern match statement like below which works:

```
if (viewModel is StudentViewModel pageModel)
{
}
```

I would like to check if viewModel is either a StudentViewModel or ParentViewModel. Is it possible to achieve this without having to write a switch statement or another if statement?

Comment: I dont get why people downvote a genuine question? Atleast when you downvote, will be great if you leave a comment about why was it downvoted

Answer (score -1):

You can test if viewModel is one of two classes like so:

```
if (viewModel is StudentViewModel || viewModel is ParentViewModel) {
  // ... viewModel is either a StudentViewModel  or a ParentViewModel
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But you answer ignores the pageModel variable. Thats important for me as it used within the method, and viewModel is of type object

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, I missed that. Since the type checking happens at runtime, there's no way to use the "c is type varname" construct in conjunction with an or/case, since the variable type can resolve to two different types. Best bet I think is `if (viewModel is StudentViewModel pageModel) { } else if (viewModel is ParentViewModel parentModel) { }`. Or if you really need to share the logic, you could possibly refactor the classes to share a parent class.

Comment: Thanks @spenster. Appreciate your reply. I have done it that way for now